# HTML EDM Overlay Elements without using <div>

Tags: html, css, overlay

I'm currently creating a HTML EDM and I have some images i want to overlay. I actually used this method http://jsfiddle.net/sqJtr/ which works and my images display correctly when I view it in a web browser. But when i try to send it in an email, the div tags are completely ignored and my images run all over the place.

```
<table class="newsletter" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <!--MASTHEAD ROW-->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="container">
                <!-- LOGO -->
                <div id="overlay_logo">
                    <img src="" width="140"/>
                </div>

                <!-- MESSAGE FROM THE DEAN -->
                <div id="main_image">
                    <img src="" width="475"/>
                </div>

                <!-- SIDE GRAPHIC -->
                <div id="overlay_sidegraphic"></div>

                <!-- HEADLINE -->
                <div id="overlay_headline">
                    <!--DATE-->
                    <div class="date">31st August 2015</div>
                    <!--TITLE-->
                    <div class="title">Congratulations</div>
                </div>

                <!-- MESSAGE CONTENT -->
                <div id="overlay_content">
                    <div class="message">
                        <!-- INTRO -->
                        <b>Dear Staff,</b>
                        <br />
                        <!-- CONTENT -->
                        <br />
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis aliquam a orci eget pretium. Donec congue sit amet erat et pharetra. 
                        Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed a feugiat quam. Nulla lorem enim, rhoncus quis venenatis ac, pellentesque ut magna. In vitae lectus tempor, 
                        pharetra felis sit amet, fringilla sem. Nunc interdum erat nec tortor efficitur, 
                        eget aliquam lectus malesuada. Nulla neque enim, viverra quis interdum quis, faucibus ac mauris. Fusce lacinia lorem in mollis semper. 
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I understand that tables should be used in place of div tags but I have no idea how to do it and I need to overlay several images. I have tried to search about it but most of the useful ones are using `<div>` tags, which doesn't work for me. Would appreciate some guidance about this. Thank you!

Comment: You can't stack images in an email because the position attribute is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used a html table generator http://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables# to create tables and added extra columns and rows to use as padding to replace divs since divs in outlook don't work.

It's quite confusing using a table with extra columns/rows as padding but at least it worked for me.